# Best way to store different large matrices in Fortran

Tags: oop, matrix, fortran, large-data

I need to store panel information of different bodies into matrices. Each matrix will contain all info for one body. So N bodies will leads to N matrices. However, the total number of bodies will be decided by user input.

I am looking for a way to create the matrices separately. The for loop index-----i would be part of the matrix name so that the matrix size can vary depending on the specific body. The idea is like:

```
for i = 1:N      

        for j = 1: ROW

                 for k = 1: COL

                           Mat_i (j,k) = panel(j,k)
                 end
        end
end
```

Is it feasible in Fortran? Is there any other way to achieve the similar effect?

Answer (score 1):

The index can't be part of the variable name.  But you can accomplish this with a user-defined type:

```
type body_type
   real, dimension (:,:), allocatable :: panel
end type body_type

type (body_type), dimension (:), allocatable :: bodies
```

Then when the user tells you `N`, allocate the array of bodies:

```
allocate (bodies (N))
```

Then when know the dimensions of the arrays, allocate them in a loop over i:

```
allocate (bodies (i) % panel (ROW_i,COL_i))
```

If the bodies have additional properties (e.g., mass, color, ...) you can include them as additional items inside the type.  Grouping related quantities in this manner is good programming practice.